# Как отключить полностью безопасный режим (не выйти, не войти, а отключить)

Tags: cmd, реестр

Вся суть вопроса в названии, требуется сделать так, чтоб пользователь не мог зайти в безопасный режим, вариант с HKLM пробовал, не хватает прав(пробовал и от админа), а мне это нужно как-то реализовать через CMD, и никак иначе.